# Array length in angularjs returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

JS:

```
function UserController($scope, User, Group){

    $scope.users = User.query();

    $scope.isNewUser = function(){

            var len = $scope.users.lenght;
            console.log(len); //undefined

            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                if($scope.users[i].created_at == null){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In frontend I have a list of users that are rendered well. However when I retrieve the length I get undefined. Why? I need the length of users to loop through the array of objects.

Comment: when i use this in view {{users.length}} and if have data than ok but if null than it shows random/garbage value .how to fix it

Answer (score 118, accepted):

use:

```
$scope.users.length;
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.users.lenght;
```

And next time "spell-check" your code.

Comment: welcome to the magic world of "everything-is-a-runtime-error" languages. No more compile errors baby!

Comment: I avoid this by using jslint/jshint, which is built into Codekit and tells me if I have any errors each time I save the JS file. The console does not flag these errors, so these features are vital to efficient coding. Otherwise you may spend hours trying to fix a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
$scope.users.data.length;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var leg= $scope.name.length;
$log.info(leg);
```

Comment: Would be nice to add a few words on what exactly you are suggesting.